# What's causing this "undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class" error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have...

**rake routes:**

```
edit_report_question
GET
/reports/:report_id/questions/:id/edit(.:format)
questions#edit
```

**questions_controller.rb:**

```
  def edit
    @report = Report.find(params[:report_id])
    @questions = @report.questions.find(params[:id])
  end
```

**report.rb:**

```
has_many :questions
```

**question.rb:**

```
belongs_to :report
```

**edit.html.haml:**

```
.textbox
  = render "shared/notice"
  %h1 Edit Question
  = render "form"
  = render "actions"
```

**_form.html.haml:**

```
= simple_form_for [@report, @question] do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = f.association :report
  = f.input :description
  = f.input :blueprint_name, :label => "Blueprint Name"
  = f.input :blueprint_url, :label => "Blueprint URL"
  = f.association :element, :label => "Website Element"
  = f.association :standard
  - if params[:action]=~ /edit/
    = f.association :fields, :as => :select
  = f.button :submit, :id => 'submit_question'
```

**params:**

```
{"action"=>"edit", "controller"=>"questions", "report_id"=>"1", "id"=>"1"}
```

Why then am I getting a "undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class" error?

Note: at present each report has many questions, but eventually I want reports to have many and belong to many questions.

Comment: Where is your @question defined that you are using in simple_form_for ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not defined '@question' anywhere in the controller, i think your controller action should be like

```
def edit
  @report   = Report.find(params[:report_id])
  @question = @report.questions.find(params[:id]) # replacing @questions with @question
end
```

You are getting nil class error because @questions is an instance variable and don't have anything in it. Plus please try to dig out before posting. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

the line that's causing the error is this line

```
simple_form_for [@report, @question]
```

since in the controller, you dont have @question variable, Rails can't infer the path of the form.  I think `@questions` there should be `@question`

```
@questions = @report.questions.find(params[:id])
```